# Merging keys and values in a dictionary - LINQ

Tags: c#

I have class defined like the following:

```
public class CoinRepository 
    {
        private Dictionary<Coin, int> repository;

        public CoinRepository()
        {
            repository = new Dictionary<Coin, int>();
        }

        public void Add(List<Coin> coins)
        {
            foreach (var coin in coins)
            {
                repository[coin] = repository.ContainsKey(coin) ? repository[coin] + 1 : 1;               
            }
        }      
    }       

   public class Coin
   {
     public int CoinValue { get; set; }
    //Has equals, hascode etc implemented. Omitted here for brevity.
   }
```

My add method will get called multiple times and I want that foreach loop shortened down by a LINQ query.

Basically what I need to do is group by all the coins by their coinvalues, and then add to the repository. However while doing that I need to merge with the ones which is present there already. How can I achieve this using LINQ?

For example: say I have 2 coins say of value 1 & 2 availiable in the repository,and I get another add request for coins by values 1,2 and 3 then my repository will now have 3 types of coins. Coin with value 1 with count 2, coin with value 2 with count 2 and coin with value 3 with count 1.

Thanks,
-Mike

Using .NET 3.5

Comment: What you're currently doing is the least amount of work possible. You can't shorten the loop down with LINQ. It'll be more expensive. The only reason to do it in LINQ is to make it more expressive, but I don't think that'll be the case. You'll still have to do a loop to modify the values in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This rather assumes you have a collection of coins to process.

It looks like you're trying to build a dictionary of coin vs coin frequency, right? In which case, the solution can be stated in a single line.

```
var dict = coins.GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

If instead, you're looking to create a dictionary of coin vs total CoinValue :

```
var dict = coins.GroupBy(c => c)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(c => c.CoinValue));
```

Comment: You mean: var dict = coins.GroupBy(c => **c.CoinValue**).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

Comment: The user's code vs their question makes it somewhat ambiguous. As I understand it, due to hash and equality being implemented, this is implicit.

Comment: This does not take care of the exisitng coins in the dictionary, or does it?

Comment: @Mike: no. But realistically, how many coins will you have. Why not throw new coins in a list and run the query when required?

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with LINQ. LINQ is for querying data structures, not modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

`LINQ` is not an effective tool for executing side effects, it is a query tool.  Since you are attempting to modify an existing collection by merging a 2nd collection, it is not the right tool for the job.

Your `foreach` loop is already pretty effective and probably as fast (or faster) than anything you can with LINQ.